# Errors while fetching from array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I wrote that kind of code

```
int[] count = new int[10];
int i = count.length;
int position = -1;
int num = kb.nextInt();

    while(i > 0)
    {
        if(count[i] == num)
        {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
         i--;
    }
```

but I got `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error

Intention was to find the last occurrence of number chosen by user in array.

Comment: How hard is it to read the error and figure it out?  You have an array that runs from [0,9] inclusive, but your value for i fell outside that range.

Comment: Thank you all for help, and sorry for disturbing you with so stupid question. Thank you for all explanation again.
The easiest is the hardest.

Comment: As a side note, you should probably be using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set `i = count.length;`. Arrays are indexed from 0 in java and so `count[count.length]` is out of bounds. The last valid index in an array `a` is `a.length -1`.

Answer (score 4):

In your first iteration, you access `count[count.length]`.

Arrays are zero-based, so you should initialize

```
int i = count.length-1;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong :

```
int i = count.length;
...
while(i > 0)
{
  if(count[i] == num)//count[count.length] is out of bound. Maximum index is count.length-1
```

Try

```
int i = count.length-1;
...
while(i >= 0)
{
```

Answer (score 2):

Your array "count" has a length of 10.
Java arrays start with index 0. Therefore the last element is at length-1 = 9

you start with i = count.length = 10.

count[10] will throw that exception.

Quick solution of your problem:

```
int i = count.length - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class arra {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);
int[] count = new int[10];
int i = count.length-1;
int position = -1;
int num = kb.nextInt();

while(i > 0)
{
    if(count[i] == num)
    {
        position = i;
        break;
    }
     i--;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your first **i** value is 10, which is the size of your array +1 --> causes the IndexOutOfBoundException
When you iterate, always substract 1 to the value youwant to have : to access the "first" value, chose index 0, for the "last", index is 9 ;)

Answer (score 0):

It will be right:

```
 int[] count = new int[10];
    int i = count.length;
    int position = -1;
    int num = kb.nextInt();

    while(i > 0)
    {
        i--;
        System.out.println(i);
        if(count[i] == num)
        {
            position = i;
            break;
        }

    }
```

The array consists of 10 items, starts at 0 and ends at 9